# Trying to initialize karma config file using "karma init". but not working

Tags: node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

[image]

I have installed the above packages of npm . Even reinstalled nodejs to its latest version. Still when I am giving command "**karma init** , its not executing anything that is it's not opening the karma config file set-up. Please help..

Comment: When you did `npm i -g karma` did it actually install it? Did you have any errors? Do you see karma installed when you run `npm list -g karma`?

Comment: C:\Users\Sunny\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- karma@0.13.22

I saw this when i run npmlist -g karma

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the 'karma' command, you will need to install the following:

`npm install -g karma-cli`

As specified by th [official documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/installation.html): you need a separate package to use karma within command line interface

Otherwise you would need to call karma from within the node_modules folder everytime

Comment: I have tried that too. Still am getting the same thing.

Comment: hmm, and if you just do `karma`, does it give you any info about karma? Also, can you make sure that you have `C:\Users\Sunny\AppData\Roaming\npm` added to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: ya thats added to the path variable. And if i juss do karma ,its not giving anything

Comment: I am not getting the actual cause of it. Please help me to start karma init properly..